# AJAX connecting to local host?

Tags: javascript, android, ajax

I am designing javascript which can call php on a server (currently my own local computer)

Eventually, I will be using phonegap to interpret the javascript and display the results...

My problem seems to be connecting to the actual server.

Here's my javascript:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1/myfiles/WorkingVersionVQuickLook.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("ipaddress=208.74.76.5");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>AJAX</h2>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Request data</button>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

It works when instead of the localhost followed by the location, I reference just WorkingVersionVQuicklook.php like this:

```
 xmlhttp.open("POST","WorkingVersionVQuickLook.php",true)
```

But once I add the exact location on the localhost it does not.

When I export to my emulator for Android, even the version that does work will not work on the emulator, which led me to the idea that I should specify its on the local machine. But because it does not even work when I do not run it via browser, it will not work on the emulator.

Please help me create a successfully mapped out connection so it will work for a browser, and then hopefully for my android!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Potential solution:

First, I think you're probably missing the port number in the absolute URL. Second, you need to use the IP-address used to connect to your computer from other computers on your network. This is because the emulator runs as its own virtualized machine, so using localhost or a relative URL will cause the request to be sent to the specified path on the emulator, not to the path in your main OS's file system.

(Edited to more directly answer the question)

Comment: So let's say I port forward and access it. Do I need to specify the port with the request? and where does that go in the syntax?

Comment: and for that matter, is the sytax of http://<ipaddress>/myfiles/working.php good enough to direct it to the correct file

Comment: The URL you use in your request should be http://<ipaddress>:<port>/myfiles/working.php (assuming the myfiles directory is in the root of your web server's public folder)

Comment: it still didn't work on the emulator :( It is at the root of the web server's public folder though... could it be a permission problem with my network?

Comment: It _could_ be. The file needs to be world readable/executable. It would be strange if the file had the wrong permissions though. The permissions should be 755 (-rwxr-xr-x). It would be helpful if you could provide an error message from the console, as that would provide an indication of where to start debugging. Can you now access the file with the absolute URL in your browser?

Comment: I cannot. It gave me the error: Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to <ipaddress>. I tried it with firefox and got similar results...

Comment: Then the port is likely blocked or your web server isn't running.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `/myfiles/WorkingVersionVQuickLook.php` and not `http://127.0.0.1/myfiles/WorkingVersionVQuickLook.php`.  Connecting to different hosts using XHR can get tricky.

Comment: This works when I do it in my browser. However when I switch it over to the android app, the page loads, but upon clicking the button nothing happens. I think the path is not clear to the android device. Advice on this?

Comment: Or perhaps you could suggest a differennt way of connecting through javascript or html?

Comment: I would try to use Ajax/Zepto for this - they tend to handle these things very well.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding... I found this type of code under w3 school's ajax tutorial. what ajax are you referencing if this is not it?

Comment: Writing lots of "standards-based" JS will give you lots of headaches.  Try using jquery (see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: I appreciate all your input. I have moved on to JQuery, but have run into another similar problem. Perhaps you might be able to give me some insight there? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458359/jquery-used-to-contact-api